# How to add pagination to wpbakery grid?

Tags: plugins, php, ajax, pagination

I have a theme with wpbakery page builder. I made a page to display blog posts using wpbakery grid. But I would like to display 5 posts per page and to use ajax pagination. I display 5 posts per page using a custom query (cat=20&posts_per_page=5). But how to integrate ajax pagination for the same?

Comment: somebody please help me on this